# How to return a proper 404 error from Extbase with a error handling configuration

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

**TYPO3 Version: 9.5.4**

**Goal:** I want to return a 404 error from an Extbase controller with the proper status code etc. that uses the configuration for 404 error handling I set up in the site configuration.

**Check that 404 handling works:** I setup a 404 error handling in the site configuration. This should show the content of a specific page. If I go to www.my-domain.local/asdfasdf I will get a 404 status code with the content of the page I specified

**What did I try in Extbase:**

```
# In the action    
return GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ErrorController::class)->pageNotFoundAction(
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST'],
        'The requested page does not exist',
        ['code' => PageAccessFailureReasons::PAGE_NOT_FOUND]
    );
```

**Result:**

Variant A (No error handling in site configuration): Exception with status code 404 > O.K

Variant B (Error handling to show content of page): Page renders with status 200, shows normal content of said page (header, footer etc.) > Not O.K

**Question:** How do I get Extbase to do the same thing as the normal pages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just return this response in your action, the page rendering is in process and does not get interrupted. Pass the response to an **ImmediateResponseException** to let the ErrorHandler handle it.

```
$response = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ErrorController::class)->pageNotFoundAction(
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST'],
    'Your error message',
    ['code' => PageAccessFailureReasons::PAGE_NOT_FOUND]
);
throw new ImmediateResponseException($response);
```

Comment: You are fantastic, that works exactly as it should. Thank you very much!